# Voltage divider in a compensator

Tags: loop-gain

In a compensator (could be any type), the lower resistor from the voltage divider (R4 in the image below) is not included into the transfer function of the compensator, meaning it doesn't impact the AC analysis. However, it seems to influence with a gain. I'm not sure how to choose the value of R4 so that my control works or what I'm missing. Most resources don't say anything about R4.

Even though I design my compensator based on the gain and phase of the plant alone, my controller still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Calling @VerbalKint.

Answer (score 2):

The inverting input is a virtual ground at AC, so R4 falls out of the calculation entirely, because it's connected between a virtual ground and a true ground.

R4 would play into the transfer function if your op amp is sufficiently nonideal, but that's more a sign that you should be using a different op amp, not that you should adjust your calculations.